# Datatables grande volume de dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-datatables

Estou pesquisando soluções para carregar um grande volume de dados em uma página com Datatables e gostaria de saber se o Datatables já possuim alguma função em que ele vai requisitando junto ao server porções de dados através de um offset? (via requisição Ajax)?

Caso contrário, vocês possuem alguma outra solução para esse caso?

P.S.: Estou procurando se alguém aqui já possuiu tal experiência antes de fazer um método no controller do Front-end que vai requisitando porções de dados junto a API até preencher a quantidade total na tabela.

Comment: Querido downvoter, quando fizer isso, por favor, justifique para que possa melhorar o conteúdo da pergunta visando atender casa vez mais pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Eai brow, o datatables é uma ótima ferramenta, porém é péssima para utilização para grandes volumes de dados. Então, nós desenvolvedores utilizamos paginação dinâmica. Segue um tutorial do site DevMedia que irá te auxiliar na criação de paginação dinâmica com a página na URL utilizando $_GET. Por falta de informações, concluí que você está desenvolvendo estruturado. Porém, se você tiver utilizando frameworks como o Symfony, Laravel, Codeigniter ou outros, eles possuem componentes que simplificam bastante o processo. E por fim, se você implementou via $_GET, irá facilmente conseguir implementar via Ajax.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/paginacao-em-php/21972

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim dá uma olha aqui:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

E aqui:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax